# How do you find the area of the shaded region between 2 lines and a curve?

Tags: calculus

I understand that this should be very fundamental, to calculus but I just can't think of a way to solve it. I've tried evaluating all the coordinates and still can't get an answer.

[image: area_bounded_by_curves]

Comment: If you draw a vertical line through $R$, does it suggest anything to you?

Comment: Easiest way may be area of trapezoid minus area between parabola and lower line

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the area of the curve(2 to 4) from the area under the straight line(from 0 to 4) then you have just have to subtract the smaller area under y=x(from 0 to 2) , i got the answer as 10.